# Automatically Show/Hide items in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery.

I would like to modify the bootstrap component in such a way that the fields appear one after the other in a loop over a certain period of time.
When the default "click" event (bootstrap collapse) is triggered on any element, time will be reset and the loop will start iterating from that element.
I want this to loop continuously through the divs until the visitor leaves the page.
How to achieve such an effect?

This is an example of a bootstrap component I would like to do this on:

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExampleOne" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExampleOne">
    Link with href
  </a>
  
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExampleOne">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExampleTwo" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExampleTwo">
    Link with href
  </a>
  
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExampleTwo">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

I need step by step help to achieve this.
I am new on stackoverflow, but I learn fast so bear with me :)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are the "fields" in that example html, which should *"appear one after the other"*?

Comment: Sorry, I meant this <div class="collapse"></div> element

Comment: So just one field per collapsable link? Can you explain then what you mean by *"one after the other"* and how this would be done *"continuously"*?

Comment: I need something like this https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/interactive-world-map-css/ but in addition to being clickable, the divs need to appear in sequence automatically

Comment: Do you mean that when you expand one element, any other expanded element is collapsed?

Comment: Yes. Only one item is expanded at a time. Others remain collapsed

Comment: Maybe also add the relevant `bootstrap` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add these three lines of JS code to only allow one collapsible to be expanded at a time:

```js
$("a[data-toggle]").click(function () {
    $(".collapse").not($(this).attr("href")).collapse("hide");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExampleOne" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExampleOne">
    Link with href
  </a>
  
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExampleOne">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExampleTwo" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExampleTwo">
    Link with href
  </a>
  
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExampleTwo">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```